# NGINX : Block from location and if caught parameter is empty

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm stuck in an existing issue. I'm trying to deny user if they tried to access a certain location page without a parameter that I've configured in `nginx.conf`
by using this parameter `$remote_user`

So is there any way i can include in the location , if i detect the remote user is empty and accessing the link. Can i deny them?

```
location ^~ /eas/monitor_alarm/

{
 proxy_pass http://myserver.com/monitor_alarm/;
}
```

Default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name myserver.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  keepalive_timeout     90;
  proxy_connect_timeout       90;
  proxy_send_timeout          90;
  proxy_read_timeout          90;
  send_timeout                90;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

location ~ (?:^|/)\. {
   deny all;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding an `if` statement? e.g. `if ($remote_user = "") { return 403; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith, that would block all the user, was looking to provide some user with the remote_user to navigate but empty remote_user will be denied.

Comment: Isn't that what the `if` statement does? If the `$remote_user` is empty, the user is denied?

Comment: @RichardSmith, yes true. If the remote_user is empty for a location ill deny. But if the remote_user is not empty i'll allow them to access. But i'm not looking to block overall but just for specific location

Comment: The `if` statement should be placed inside the `location` to reduce its scope. The `return` directive is one of the permissible statements for an if in location context. See [this link](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).